# The text in One Note file type is not being extracted properly by apache tika

Tags: apache-tika

one line is being shown multiple times in the extracted output.

I tried using writing the oneNoteParser instead of autodetect parser but still the output is same.

I didn't find any bug about this in apache tika website too. May be it needs changes in apache tika side code.